# Delete image file from directory in PHP on remote server and localhost

Tags: php, localhost, delete-file, remote-server

I'm trying to figure out, how to delete correctly image file with [summernote](https://summernote.org/) from directory folder on remote server and localhost.

So, image successfully uploaded from summernote editor and located by directory path:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/user/blog/uploads/img-uploads/154_20220702.png
```

and `C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\admin\editor-delete.php` code:

```
<?php
    $src  = $_POST['src']; 
    $path = "../uploads/img-uploads/";
    $dir = basename($path);
    $file_name = str_replace($dir, '', $src);
    unlink($file_name);
    if ($file_name) {          
        echo 'File Delete Successfully';
    }
?>
```

or

```
$src  = $_POST['src'];
$dir = "../uploads/img-uploads/";
$file_name = str_replace($dir, '', $src);
unlink($file_name);
if ($file_name) {
    echo 'File Delete Successfully';
}
```

> Warning:  unlink(): http does not allow unlinking in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\admin\editor-delete.php

```
$src  = $_POST['src'];
$dir = "../uploads/img-uploads/";
$file_name = str_replace($dir, '', $src);
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file_name);
if ($file_name) {
    echo 'File Delete Successfully';
}
```

Localhost correct path must be `C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/uploads/img-uploads/154_20220702.png`, but with `unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $file_name);` the path contains extra `http://localhost/user/` in `C:/xampp/htdocs/http://localhost/user/blog/uploads/img-uploads/154_20220702.png`

> Warning:
> unlink(C:/xampp/htdocshttp://localhost/user/blog/uploads/img-uploads/154_20220702.png):
> No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\admin\editor-delete.php
>
> File Delete Successfully
>
> jquery-3.6.0.min.js:5177 XHR finished loading: POST
> "http://localhost/user/blog/admin/editor-delete.php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot completely test this but I think you could change the `editor-delete.php` script like this. Judging by the paths cited in the question you need to construct the absolute path by leaving the admin directory traversing the file structure into `uploads/img-uploads` so `chdir` and `getcwd` are two useful functions for this. The notes in the code show what I mean.

The piece of code that displays the `File Delete Successfully` is based upon a variable which will always be true (effectively) rather than the more meaningful result from the actual `unlink` operation so you should use that returned value to fork your program logic.

```
<?php

    /* 
        C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\admin\editor-delete.php
        
        so:
        
        chdir('../') leads to C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\
        chdir('../uploads/img-uploads') should lead to C:\xampp\htdocs\user\blog\uploads\img-uploads
    */
    
    
    if( isset( $_POST['src'] ) ){
    
        # Change working directory for current script operations
        # - go up one level out of "admin" and into the uploads folder.
        
        chdir('../uploads/img-uploads');
        
        
        # default value for use later in output message
        $status=false;
        
        # construct the full path to local file using getcwd() to find working directory.
        $path=sprintf( '%s/%s', getcwd(), basename( $_POST['src'] ) );
        
        # if the file exists - delete it or warn ( inspect the path! )
        if( file_exists( $path ) )$status=@unlink( $path );
        else exit( sprintf( 'Unable to find file: "%s"', $path ) );
        
        # prevent cached results tainting file checks
        clearstatcache();
        
        
        echo $status ? 'File deleted successfully' : 'Sorry, that file could not be deleted';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry for late replay. The code works perfectly on Localhost, but I did not check it yet on the remote server. To check the blog on both local and remote, I've to use the condition:  'if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']))'  and add different path for remote, which should be '$src' directly, or I've missed something?